# Scrollable horizontal view under navigation bar on iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

[image: Scrollable row on top of Collection View]

How do I do this scrollable left and right on top of the CollectionView / TableView? Is there any tutorial of this for iOS Swift?

Comment: You can have a header view for your tableview/collection view, and in that, again one more collection view having all your buttons as cells...

Comment: @Shripada Then how could make it scrollable? Is the headerView scrollable left and right as default?

Comment: Header view is not, but the collection view that is added as a subview to the header view is scrollable @Jefferyleo

Comment: @Shripada then how about table view?